# how to choose an activity after clicking on a notification?

Tags: android, notifications

**the problem:** When I build the notification I can know where I am in my app in that moment and with a Pending Intent I can say to my notification what is the activity to open after user perform a click on  notification. But if I continue to navigate in my app I loose the information about what is last activity I opened.

**the target:** I'd like that when the user perform a click on my app's notification: if the user is in my app then nothing to do else if the user is out then open the last activity that he/she saw.

```
protected NotificationCompat.Builder initBaseNotificationBuilder() {

    NotificationCompat.Builder notifBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
    notifBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
    notifBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    notifBuilder.setOnlyAlertOnce(false);
    notifBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notifBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> services = activityManager
            .getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    boolean isActivityFound = false;

    if (services.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName()
            .equalsIgnoreCase(mContext.getPackageName())) {
        isActivityFound = true;
    }

    PendingIntent notifyPIntent;
    if (isActivityFound) {
        notifyPIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext.getApplicationContext(), 0,
                intent, 0);
    } else {
        notifyPIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext.getApplicationContext(), 0,
                new Intent(), 0);
    }

    notifBuilder.setContentIntent(notifyPIntent);
    return notifBuilder;
}
```

the `.getRunningTasks()` method is deprecated.

There is a solution? There is a method that solve this problem?
Thanks.